# Using web3.js to interface with smart contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapps

I am a beginner in Dapp and don't know about web3.js. I complie myslef contracts with Truffle. I did write the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

  contract TEST{
    bytes public name="Yerevan is love";

    function fname() public view returns(string memory){
      return string(name);
     }
   }
```

and i want to see the "Yerevan is love" by alert() dialogbox in JavaScript code. Truffle provided the following .js file to interface between browser and smart contract:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: async function() {
    // Load pets.
    $.getJSON('../pets.json', function(data) {
      var petsRow = $('#petsRow');
      var petTemplate = $('#petTemplate');

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        petTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
        petTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-breed').text(data[i].breed);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-age').text(data[i].age);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-location').text(data[i].location);
        petTemplate.find('.btn-adopt').attr('data-id', data[i].id);

        petsRow.append(petTemplate.html());
      }
    });

    return await App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: async function() {
    /*
     * Replace me...
     */

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    /*
     * Replace me...
     */

    return App.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-adopt', App.handleAdopt);
  },

  markAdopted: function(adopters, account) {
    /*
     * Replace me...
     */
  },

  handleAdopt: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    /*
     * Replace me...
     */
  }

};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

I can see "Yerevan is love" in truffle console  but i want do this in browser. I don't know about working with the above codes.

Comment: You normally would use something like Metamask to connect from frontend to a contract https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/.

Comment: There is an appropriate solution code [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79840/access-to-smart-contracts-value-in-browser/82405#82405).